# how to use transitive shared dependency in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries

We have a package:
My static lib
target name: mystaticlib
Dependencies: pugixml::shared
the dependency is defined similar to:
target_link_libraries(mystaticlib pugixml::shared)
when we install this lib, we place a copy of the libpugixml.so inside the install similar to

```
following:
install
...... lib
...... |...... mystaticlib.lib
...... |...... libpugixml.so
...... mystaticlibConfig.cmake
```

now we use this package in another project new_tooling, and we find the package using find_package(mystaticlib)
In new_tooling, we have an executable: my_new_executable and a line similar to:
target_link_libraries(my_new_executable mystaticlib)
the dependency of mystaticlib: pugixml::shared now transitively becomes a dependency of my_new_executable
How can we make the install of mystaticlib such that this transitive dependency is automatically found in the same folder as mystaticlib by clien

Comment: How are you aquiring pugixml? Do you search it using `find_package`? Do you download it using fetch content? Is it part of your source-tree (git modules or similar)? Please post the important parts of you cmake scripts

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: SO I have a package A which is dependent on lib B and B is depend on C but A is also dependent on C so when I try to add the dependency of B in A it working But I also need to link the A with C and the C .lib or .so files are in the Install folder of B so how can I link A with C using the install folder of B
@local-ninja